# ngFor with JSON object - Angular 2 ngmodel perspective

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have been trying to do a simple task of taking an input in textbox and listing the same. The sample code is below:
Example.html:

```
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name" placeholder="Enter a name here">

<!-- conditionally display `yourName` -->
<button (click)="getData(user)">Add</button>
<hr>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let rec of record">{{rec.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And code in example.ts is below:

```
 record:any[]=[];
  user={"name":""};
  getData(username:any){
    this.record.push(username);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.record));
  }
```

Th problem i face is, when i insert the second input , even the first input changes as second as both refer to the same ngModel.For instance, if i add "GG" as input, first record will be GG . When i enter "HH" then, first record GG changes to HH and result will be HH and HH. Please help me understand where i went incorrect and help solve this.

Comment: Can you add complete code, how you add more inputs? There are https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms with description how to add Array of FormGroups.

Comment: @AntonM. I add single name in input box. On click of add, it gets passed to list. In the same input box, i add another input too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your object has same key name every time while pushing the object will get updated with new value so how have do like this

```
 this.record.push(Object.assign({}, username));
```

Read about Object.assign() from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: This is something i exactly looked for. Thanks!

Comment: glad I could help! Have a great day and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have understood correctly that the problem is caused by the objects having same reference. As you are trying to store user details in a simple object you can easily clone the object by changing

```
this.record.push(username);
```

TO

```
this.record.push(_.clone(username));
```

The `_.clone` is a [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#clone) function which will pass a new object instead of a reference.

You can also try a quick fix ( highly discouraged due to performance reasons );

```
this.record.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(username)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions firstly. Cloning is something even I thought of. Other than that, I wonder how the second solution worked. Could you please let me know it?